# Can You Construct a Syndetic Set with an Undefined Density?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, measure-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{N}$. Enumerate $A = \{A_1, A_2,...\}$ such that $A_1 \le A_2 \le ...$. We say that $A$ is syndetic if there exists some $M \geq 0$ such that $A_{i+1} - A_i \le M$ for all $i =1,2,..$ (that is, "the gaps of $A$ are uniformly bounded"). The natural density of $A$, if it exists, is defined to be
$$d(A) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{|A \cap \{1,2,..., N\}|}{N} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{N}{A_N}.$$
It is possible that the limit does not exist. The examples of this phenomenon that I've seen all use the same idea. You need to have a set which first contains a lot of elements of $\{1,2,..N\}$, then misses a lot of $\{N, N+1, ..., N'\}$ then has a lot of $\{N' + 1, ..., N''\}$, etc. A common example is given by
$$A = [2^3, 2^5] \cup [2^7, 2^9] \cup ... \cup [2^{4k-1}, 2^{4k+1}] \cup ...$$
Such examples cannot be syndetic. In the specific given example the problem is that the gaps $[2^{4k+1}, 2^{4k + 5}]$ are not bounded as $k \to \infty$.

So my question is: how can one construct a syndetic set with no natural density (if possible)? Even better: can you construct $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $A$ and $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$ are syndetic and such that $A$ has no density?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the union of the even integers and a subset of odd integers whose density fluctuates (say between 1/4 and 1/8 of odd numbers, to meet the other conditions).

Comment: Here's a concrete answer, based on the same idea.

Let $E$ be $2\mathbb{N}$, let $F$ be the elements of $4\mathbb{N}$ with an even number of digits, and let $G$ be elements of $4\mathbb{N}+1$ with an odd number of digits. Let $A=E\setminus F \cup G$.

$A$ is syndetic with $M=5$, because it contains the set $\{2,6,10,14,\dots\}$. It has no natural density, because it has densities within the consecutive intervals $[10^k,10^{k+1})$ of 3/4 when $k$ is odd and is 1/4 when $k$ is even. $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ also has no natural density, and it's syndetic because it contains $\{3,7,11,15,\dots\}$.

Comment: Thanks.  Another one: include integers that are +1 mod 3, to make the set syndetic.  Exclude the -1 mod 3, to make the complement syndetic.  Union with $3 \times$ any set without a density.